# symfony2 form with a many to many entity

Tags: symfony

I have this form with manyTomany relation working perfectly like this:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('manifestations', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PrifProtocoleBundle:Manifestation',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'property' => 'libelle',
                'empty_value' => 'Choississez',
                'required' => false,));
}
```

but i want to set the'multiple' parameter to 'false', this way, i just have a select box with the option 'Choississez', so when i click on it, it displays all the other values. Unfortunately i get an error message: nor of the methods _*set()" or "*_call()" exist and have public access in class. i've been searching for some solutions on the web and tried this one:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('manifestations', 'collection', array(
                'type' => 'entity', 
                'options' => array(
                'class' => 'AcmeProtoBundle:Manifestation',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'property' => 'libelle',
                'empty_value' => 'Choisissez',
                'required' => false,)));
}
```

i have no error message! but the select form doesn't display even when i set the 'multiple' to 'true, i only have the submit button, when clicked shows me the results, so i think i miss something in the parameters to display the form!

can anyone help? Thanks

## Manifestation.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ManifestationRepository")
 */
```

class Manifestation {

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->dateCreation = new \DateTime;
    $this->dateModif = new \DateTime;
}

public function __toString() {
    return $this->getLibelle();
}

/**
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Assert\GreaterThan(
 *      value = 0,
 *      message = "La valeur doit être positive"
 * )
 */
private $numOrdre;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=50)
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = "5",
 *      minMessage = "Le libellé doit faire au moins {{ limit }} caractères"
 * )
 */
private $libelle;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $dateCreation;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $dateModif;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 * @Assert\NotBlank( message=" ")
 */
private $etat;

//getters and setters
```

## invite.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="InviteRepository")
 * 
 */
```

class Invite {

```
 /**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\ProtoBundle\Entity\Manifestation", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message=" ")
 */
private $manifestations;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution working for me now with 'multiple' => false':

i've added this function in the other entity in relation with Manifestation, to consider manifestations as an array

```
    public function setManifestations($manifestations){
    if(!is_array($manifestations)){
        $manifestations = array($manifestations);
    }
    $this->manifestations = $manifestations;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your manifestation.php file (your entity)?

*Multiple* doesn't have the behaviour you are looking for : *Multiple* is used to allow a user to check multiple checkboxes (true) or only one (false) of a given form ([symfony doc : multiple](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#multiple)).

In your case a common solution is to use javascript on a parent field that would disable/enable the children fields. Make sure to add server-side validation on these fields if you go for this.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i added the files on the top! Actually the solution i tried with 'collection' parameter i found it here http://fr.openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/symfony2-formulaire-many-to-many-avec-attributs-89771, at the end of the page. the submit button shows me the results, but i think maybe i miss something in the parameter to display the select tag coz even when i put the multiple to true the form doesn't show up .

Comment: For your solution I'm not familiar with javascript could you show me an example on how to do this? Thanks

Comment: If you haven't done it already, the first thing you need to do in your entity is to create the Getter and Setters methods. There's a symfony command for it, more info here -> [link] (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters). The error message you get is about these getter/setter methods.

Comment: Then, in the link you provide, the user is trying to show a form with an "add a field" button : that's what "collections" are for. Is it what you are trying to achieve here?